# How do I re-enable an "Item" in Bundle Settings for Textmate?

Tags: textmate

So I went to `Bundles -> Edit Bundles` and then picked `PHP` then `Settings` and this I unchecked `Enable this` for `Indentation Rules`, and now I cannot re-enable it because it's greyed out and I cannot even click it. How can I re-enable it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is for TextMate 2 since this problem doesn't exist in TextMate 1 AFAIK.

Located inside the folder `~/Library/Application Support/Avian/Bundles/PHP.tmbundle` are all the 'deltas' for your bundles.  A 'delta' file is a record of the changes you have made to the 'standard' bundles.  TextMate records the changes rather than applying them directly to the bundle to allow the bundle to be updated without erasing your changes (among other reasons).

Find the file for the command or setting you want to reenable.  Either open the file and change the key 'isDisabled' to false if you want to keep other changes you have made, or simply delete the file if you want to revert to the default.